# Is there a common term for a fixed-length, fifo, "push through" array or list?

Tags: data-structures, terminology

Here's a ubiquitous data structure in, say, game and UX programming:

- there're a fixed number of items (say, "5")
- they're all "zero" to begin with
- you can put one in on the "left" (FWIW I usually call it something like shove to distinguish from the usual meaning of push)
- once there are 5, each time you put a new one in on the left, the one on the "right" falls out and is gone
- in fact, it's not possible to / there's no need to access any individual item, ever
- you can get the total at any time

Here's a trivial naturalistic example. (Obviously, there're several ways to do it.)

I've always wondered if there's a common term for this.

I sometimes call it a "piece of pipe" (imagine a short piece of pipe that you can push tennis balls through from one end).

```
///A "pipe" ongoing sum. First in is first thrown-away.
class Pipe {
    private var r: [Whatever] = []
    private var i: Int = 0
    private var k: Int = 0
    
    ///Start fresh, with a given fixed length.
    public func begin(with: Int) {
        k = with
        r = Array(repeating: .zero, count: k)
        i = 0
    }
    
    ///Add one on the left
    public func shove(p: CGPoint) {
        r[i] = p
        i = (i + 1) % k
    }
    
    ///Supply the current value at this moment.
    public var sum: CGPoint {
        return r.reduce(.zero, +) / CGFloat(k)
    }
    
    ///Debugging string.
    public var say: String {
        return r.reduce("pipe: "){ a,b in "\(a) .. \(b.say)"} + "   t   " + sum.say
    }
}
```

Comment: Call me naive but, it's not this a `Stack` or `Pile`? The case you describe is a stack overlfow. How the stack overflow is handled doesn't make it a different thing. That's just a policy. You could throw an error instead and it would be still a `Stack`

Comment: Is it possible you're talking about a *circular buffer*, or at least generically some kind of *buffer*? With the particular feature that no individual item is ever accessed, only the total, but the individual items are retained so as to know how the total alters when an item is dropped from the tail, I think that's possibly more a peculiarity of this application, than something that would have its own name.

Comment: Also Fattie, just trying to reconcile what @Laiv has said, are you sure the algorithm you describe is LIFO? If items fall off the right as new items are added on the left, that's FIFO surely?

Comment: @Steve (yes, sorry "lifo" was just a typo in the example code!)

Comment: hi @JonasH I find your comment confusing, in that that is exactly what is described, and indeed, that is what the code shows :)  It could be used for an "item wise" moving average, sure.  (Lots of things can be used for lots of things.)  Note that, IMO, "moving average" almost certainly means "over a given fixed period of time" rather than "over a given fixed number of items", which is quite different. (Certainly in stock markets, etc, that's the case.)

Comment: @Laiv sorry about the "l" / "f" typo.  I don't think it's a stack (the way I usually use "stack" anyways) and I don't think it's a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pile_(abstract_data_type)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852863/fixed-size-queue-which-automatically-dequeues-old-values-upon-new-enques

Comment: This statement is confusing: ` it's not possible to / there's no need to access any individual item, ever` ... if you never need to access any of the items, why bother to put them in?

Comment: @Michael ? for the sum.  All you need is the sum. (Every single time one has ever used a mouse or touched a screen, this code is in play!)

Comment: @Laiv You might want to remove that comment. The OP said that LIFO was a typo, and they were actually wanting a FIFO, so the first comment in the list is now misleading.

Comment: @Fattie For an accumulator all you need is a single storage location that you can add to... I'm still not understanding why you need a FIFO.  Not that it really matters, this is just a distraction to the actual question which works fine if you actually do need to access the data.

Comment: @micheal A LIFO is needed so that the code knows what to subtract when a new item is shoved.

Comment: Is that Swift? It might be informative to at least mention in which language the code is written.

Comment: Cheers Eric.  I think as it states it's pseudo code, and, the question is strictly about terminology.  (Although the comments have drifted off eh!  :) )

Comment: This is a circular buffer. But if you implement it using an array it is a very inefficiently implemented circular buffer. Except if you are using arrays in a language like javascript or lists in a language like lisp or tcl - then it's not inefficient because arrays/lists in those languages are basically linked lists.

Comment: @slebetman: JavaScript arrays have no defined representation, and I wouldn't count on them having linked list-like performance for FIFO queues. Some implementations might dynamically convert from sparse or dense array representations to a linked-list-like implementation based on usage (the modern JIT optimizers get crazy), but it's not something inherent in the language spec (unlike Lisp for example).

Answer (score 34):

This sounds a lot like a [circular buffer or ring buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer). It meets most of the criteria:

- It has a fixed size of items.
- They don't have to be a specific value at the start, but they could be initialized to a reasonable default, empty, or null value depending on your implementation.
- You insert values at the end and read from the marker.
- If you are writing faster than you are reading, items will fall out of the buffer before they can be read.

You could have some specialized implementations of a ring buffer that address other concerns. I suspect that it would be close enough to a ring buffer that the name would still apply and be meaningful.

Comment: Thanks.  Hmm, you know, I usually think of a circular buffer as a particular type of queue.  (In my mind: a queue is platonic, and can be as long as you want and has no performance problems "shifting everything" all the time.  Then, in my mind, a circular buffer is a good way to *implement a queue* in many situations, but it suffers from the problem you might run out of room.) Thanks to your comment it occurred to me after years that what I'm describing is indeed "a somewhat unusual queue" (ie it deliberately runs out of room all the time, and also there's no need to access items)...

Comment: ... so yeah I guess it's a ring buffer.  You know, "buffer" really intensely makes me think of, well, a buffer: there's stuff coming through and you want to slow it down so you can deal with it, not losing any.  (Losing any is bad, wrong, the whole point of a buffer is to avoid loss; in every day English that's what buffer means.) Hence my resistance to "buffer".  I guess the bottom line is it is indeed a queue. Thanks!

Comment: @Fattie We've been using the term ring buffer or circular buffer for ages. A queue is a type of buffer (things line up and wait their turn). MS-DOS, for example, had a keyboard buffer to store 16 keypresses in a 32-byte wide buffer, and would beep at you if the buffer was full on keypress/release (e.g. a program was caught in an infinite loop and so couldn't read keys). We've had fixed buffers even earlier than that, but that was my earliest recollection of the word. Ring/circular is used to distinguish between variable-sized buffers like a stack or queue.

Comment: @Fattie The reason why we would use such a buffer is on a space-limited device. Normal programming doesn't matter when you have GB of RAM, but what if you only had 64k? When every byte counts, you have to make tradeoffs somewhere, and circular buffers were a great way to store a seemingly sufficient amount of data to process. In the old days, we had fixed buffers for almost everything, UART, keyboard, mouse, etc. It was the alternative to polling, where the computer would lose data if it couldn't read the inputs at the correct time.

Comment: hi @phyrfox !  Yes, I am very old too :) You know, I really think just "queue" is better for the thing described. Perhaps just "fixed queue", something like that.

Comment: @phyrfox There’s no doubt that programming in >1GB ram is different. But even then when you’re writing code that needs its uptime in months you appreciate data structures that don’t leak memory.

Comment: The everyday meaning of "buffer" is not something that avoids losing data, it's something that sits between two other things to somehow decouple them - mechanically (for trains) or logically (for producers and consumers). Not wanting to lose data is a common property of consumers, but it's not intrinsic to the buffer. There's even an outgoing buffer somewhere for UDP sends, and those are permitted to be dropped on the floor at any time for any reason.

Comment: @Fattie But what you are doing with your data structure no matter what you call it **IS** buffering. You are **slowing down** your data stream so that your logic can process a bunch of it at a time. Otherwise, if you don't need to "slow it down", you don't need the array. You can just use a single variable and process the data as is (one piece/byte at a time)

Comment: hi @slebetman not really, you "buffer" because a vast amount of data is incoming, and, it's not practicable to process it all, and, you're concerned that you might lose some, so you buffer stuff. this has no connection, in any way, whatsoever, even vaguely, to what's being disussed. you just want to know (say) the ave speed of something happening over the last few frames  so you keep a record of the last few items and calculate it. Word have meaning and signify stuff.  Sure, regarding *everything* under discussion here I could bang my hand on the desk and say, this is an array, an array.

Comment: Everything's an array, ultimately everything's "some memory".  A ring buffer is ................................... "an array". The idea that it's a "ring" is a fantastical, absurd fantasy. There are no "rings" involved :) Chips don't have "rings"  :)  It's ........................ an array :)  It's totally normal that we use words like queues, rings, buffers, arrays, lists, etc to "describe concepts" of what is being done.

Comment: @Fattie Not really, that's just one use of "buffer" in electronics, computing. You are using a very narrow definition of the word "buffer" which is just one of the types of buffer you find in electronics. We also for example buffer voltages when there is an impedance mismatch between two circuits. We also buffer signals using a delay line (mercury inside glass tubes, very long electrical wire, very long vibrating wire etc.) when we need it to match the timing of another part of a circuit etc. A circular buffer is still a buffer.

Comment: I do note that the very Wikipedia article you quote mentions that there are _two_ ways to handle the buffer full condition: either overwriting or not. Ring Buffers are typically used in xPxC concurrent queues, and there they do NOT overwrite. Similarly, the LMax Disruptor pattern uses a Ring buffer and does NOT overwrite. With overwriting not being intrinsic to Ring Buffers, I'd argue you need to specify this property on top.

Comment: a buffer is a particular type of queue.  a ring is a particular type of queue. a linked list is a type of list. a doubly linked list is a type of linked list.  we (often, typically, but don't have to) use more and more nested terms to describe something, for convenience in the workplace, to give a sense of the mechanism and use cases. . if I said to one of my colleagues, please make me a ring buffer, she *just wouldn't* make the thing I describe, she would instantly think of .... a ring buffer :) since I said ring buffer :) and that would bring to mind a milieu of thought and use cases. so!

Comment: @Fattie You are correct that there's a million ways to say it, and you may have a colleague who would make something different when they hear "ring buffer," but I do believe those two words are the two I'd use to get someone to implement exactly the code you wrote above (alibet you'd have to add the "sum" bit in).  A quick google search and look at [wikipidia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) would point that colleague directly at that implementation -- other than I might have to say "a ring/circular buffer that drops the oldest value if it gets too full"

Answer (score 20):

Like the other answer suggests, a fixed-length fifo queue is a **[ring buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer)**, although usually writing past the capacity will be prevented, instead of overwriting the next element.

> - in fact, it's not possible to / there's no need to access any individual item, ever
> - you can get the total at any time

With this feature, it is known as a **sliding window**. I would be implemented as follows:

```
class SlidingWindow<Whatever extends Numeric> {
    private var r: [Whatever] = []
    private var i: Int = 0
    private var k: Int = 0
    ///Running sum over the contents of the sliding window
    public var sum: Whatever = .zero
    
    ///Start fresh, with a given fixed length.
    public func begin(with: Int) {
        k = with
        r = Array(repeating: .zero, count: k)
        i = 0
        sum = .zero
    }
    
    ///Add a new value, remove the oldest value, update the sum
    public func advance(p: Whatever) {
        sum = sum - r[i] + p
        r[i] = p
        i = (i + 1) % k
    }
}
```

Comment: Beware that the accumulator is subject to rounding-error for inexact numeric types (floating point). The total risks gradually drifting away from the true result.

Comment: @doynax: That's a good point. A workaround, if it's a concern, would be to recalculate the sum from scratch (by iterating over the full buffer) at regular intervals. Doing it whenever `i == 0` would be a simple and natural choice, and would keep the amortized time complexity of the `advance` operation independent of the buffer size.

Comment: As doynax says, you would never do it that way, you'd just add them all each time. (In all eg. mouse systems, input systems etc I've never seen it done as above, for the reasons stated, you just add them all.) You might do this in some obscure performance situation I can't think of an example of.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen hmm, I difficult to see any real-world reason you'd do that, you'd just cache the latest value right? (In some strange situation where it is begin "requested often") .. I'd say

Comment: Anyway this is about terminology.  Bergi just as you say "ring buffer" (and indeed buffer in general) implies the exact opposite, a device for *not* losing overflow.  Also it is a window, but, specifically *not* a sliding window, heh :)  I really think the best term is just "something queue".  Perhaps "fixed queue" or "throw-away queue" or such.

Comment: @Fattie: Keeping track of the total sum and updating it as new values are added (and pushed off) seems like a pretty natural optimization if the sums are needed frequently, and the buffer isn't so small that summing it takes negligible time. I'm surprised you haven't seen it, although I suppose it likely depends on the application domain you typically work in.

Comment: … In particular, this kind of data structure is a natural choice for applying a [boxcar convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxcar_function) (a.k.a. a [simple moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Simple_moving_average) of the past *k* data points) to a data stream, where you need to obtain the updated sum after each new data point (and in which case you'd typically just have the `advance` operation directly return the new sum). Here, having the sum update take just two arithmetic operations instead of *k* is a clear win whenever *k* ≫ 2.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen for sure, you're 100% correct in theory but as I was just saying, it's difficult to see any real-world use of that, where k is Vast and there's an incredibly frequent need for the total or average (it would be some incredibly fast time series on the electronics level perhaps?)  for things like financial markets, banking, you just have "each day's" saved as it were and you only have to fuss with the two ends (essentially your idea, but in chunks).  Anyway with use cases, of course someone will come along and say "obviously you do that in _ _ _"  :)

Comment: @Fattie: It depends on your domain. Moving average filters of non-trivial size are common in digital signal processing kernels on the critical path of the system, such as in image processing. My day job deals in underpowered embedded devices where this type of optimization is helpful in hitting real-time deadlines and power budgets. YMMV.

Comment: @Fattie "*it is a window, but, specifically not a sliding window*" - why not? It's a window sliding over the input stream

Comment: @Fattie Btw it is a pretty popular optimisation pattern, used e.g. in [SQL window functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function_(SQL)) or [digital signal processing or statistics evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function), although in there it often is not just [the simple sum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8269916/1048572).

Comment: @doynax TY, makes perfect sense (hence my guess "on the electronics level perhaps" !)

Comment: "usually writing past the capacity will be prevented, instead of overwriting the next element" -- the overwriting the oldest data is exactly what makes it a _circular_ buffer/queue as opposed to any other type.

Comment: What I meant is that the write pointer must not overtake the read pointer, otherwise the buffer would be considered empty. You'll need to first read data from the buffer before you can write to the same cell again. You cannot (or at least shouldn't) *over*write the oldest elements that have not yet been read.

Comment: @Fattie: We also need something *like* that for monitoring and alerting purposes in production. Think of it this way: Every [second/minute/hour/etc.], you scrape a value from the server and add it to your timeseries. You don't want the server to waste any time doing math to that value (it's busy serving queries), so it's just a simple monotonically-increasing counter. If you want a rate, you have to do the subtraction and division yourself, and so on. You end up with a lot of these sliding windows, some of which contain quite a lot of data points and/or do a lot of math for alerting rules.

Comment: hi @Kevin if you are scraping every "second/minute/hour" it's just "utterly inconceivable", it's beyond any rational consideration, that it could matter to add a few floats. As I think doynax pointed out, if you are dealing with actual electronics so, this problem comes up *tens of thousands of times a second* it is relevant.  the whole issue is wildly, spectacularly, inconceivably, staggeringly!, outside the domain of the question.

Comment: @Fattie: The server is updating the count every request, not every second. The server is processing *much* more than 1 query per second!